# css renders differently in other pc web browsers except in iis server

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis

I have modified the CSS files [Asp.net/VS 2008] and hosted to the iis server (windows server 2003 - IIS 6).first it didn't rendered properly. so I replace css file inside the iis server and hosted the project. Then it only rendered properly (when browse it) at IIS server. but not rendering on other PC browsers. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the CSS file path? Did you accidently include `localhost` in it?

Comment: No it is inside the inbuild css folder -<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Put the link in your browser, does the CSS file load?

Comment: do you mean inside the default.aspx page which includes the styles?

Comment: No, i mean the CSS file itself. If you paste the full path to it in your browser you should be able to see it. If you can't then you know it's an issue with the path you've used somehow

Comment: every thing loads perfectly and even rendering. but when i host at iis

Comment: Can you give me the url to your CSS file please?

Comment: yes it is there inside the the browser. even it rendered properly when browsed in iis server. but the problem is it is not getting renders in other PC machines where they are connected to. will it be a problem with the version ? or LAN Networking?

Comment: http://192.168.190.38/AbnormalAttendances.aspx?mmi=59

Comment: That's a local file path and it doesn't look like it points to a CSS file? If this is a deployed website you need to change the `192.168.190.38` part to the domain name

Comment: There is no url to give you. as we use internal CSSs' in local servers

Comment: o.k thanks I got your point